# Turn a Maude expression into a String

Tags: logic-programming, maude-system

Is there a way to turn a Maude expression into a string?

I'm looking for the equivalent of Haskell's `show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no really clean solution. You could convert the expression into 
a metaterm, metaPrettyPrint it, convert the resulting Qids to strings 
and concatenate them, but you would still need to deal with lexical 
issues, such as where to insert spaces.

(From the [Maude mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/maude-help/2012-June/000578.html))